# How to assign values to a new column based on a range of dates from that overlap years in R?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, overlap

I have a growth rate, calculated from individual measurements 4 times a year, that I am trying to assign to a different time frame called Year2 (August 1st of year 1 to July 31st of year 2, see attached photo).

[image: Terrible timeline drawing]

My Dataframe:

| ID | Date | Year | Year2 | Lag | Lapse | Growth | Daily_growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009-07-30 | 2009 | 2009 | NA | NA | 35.004 | NA |
| 1 | 2009-10-29 | 2009 | 2010 | 2009-07-30 | 91 days | 31.585 | 0.347 |
| 1 | 2010-01-27 | 2010 | 2010 | 2009-10-29 | 90 days | 63.769 | 0.709 |
| 1 | 2010-04-27 | 2010 | 2010 | 2010-01-27 | 90 days | 28.329 | 0.315 |
| 1 | 2010-07-29 | 2010 | 2010 | 2010-04-27 | 93 days | 32.068 | 0.345 |
| 1 | 2010-11-02 | 2010 | 2011 | 2010-07-29 | 96 days | 128.1617320 | 1.335 |

I took the growth rate as follows:

```
Growth_df <- Growth_df%>%
group_by(ID) %>% # Individuals we measured     
  mutate(Lag = lag(Date), #Last date measured   
         Lapse = round(difftime(Date, Lag, units = "days")), #days between Dates monitored  
         Daily_growth = as.numeric(Growth) / as.numeric(Lapse))
```

What I am trying to do is assign the daily growth rate between each measurement, matching to the Year2 timeframe:

```
Growth_df <- Growth_df %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year),
         Year2_growth = ifelse(Year == Year2, Daily_growth*Lapse, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(Year2) %>% 
  mutate(Year2_growth = sum(Year2_growth, na.rm = TRUE))
```

My problem is that I do not know how to get the dates in between the years (something in place of the 0 in the ifelse statement). I need some sort of way that would calculate how many days would be left from the new start date (August 1st) to the most recent measurement, then multiply it by the growth rate, as well as cut the end early (July 31st)

I tried making a second dataframe with nothing by years and days then assigning the growth rate when comparing the two dataframes but I have been stuck on the same issue: partitioning the time frame.

Comment: Could you please review your question and see if there's a way to clarify what you're trying to do? I don't understand yet what these sentences are referring to: "assign to a different time frame called Year2" or "assign the daily growth rate between each measurement, matching to the Year2 timeframe"

Comment: I'm guessing you might want something like 
`Growth_df %>%  tidyr::complete(ID, Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2009-08-01"), as.Date("2011-11-01"), "year")) %>%  arrange(ID, Date)` which would insert August 1st rows for each ID, from which you could continue the way you had it to calculate subsequent lags?

Comment: I am struggling to come up with the explanation myself! 

Year2 = August 31st of say 2008, to July 31st of say 2009, which would represent all the growth in this time frame up until 2009, repeating in this fashion until present) 

I need this time frame as the winter season in the southern hemisphere where I am ends around August 1st. 

"assign the daily growth rate between each measurement, matching to the Year2 timeframe":

I need to find how much each ID grew between August 1st  of one year (t) and July 31st of the next year(t+1)

Comment: Could you calculate `Daily_growth`, then do my step above to add August 1sts, then re-calc `Lapse`, and then each year's total growth would be `group_by(Year) %>% summarize(growth = sum(Lapse * Daily_growth))`?

Comment: I could not, alas. I did find a terrible solution nonetheless (see below):

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there's a much much muuuuch more efficient way to deal with this, but this is the way I sorted out:

1. Make my timeframes
2. Create a function for the ranges I wanted
3. Make a dataframe with for both the start and the end ranges
4. Join them together
5. Marvel in my lack of r skills.

```
Start_dates <-  seq(ymd('2008-08-01'),ymd('2021-08-1'), by = '12 months')
End_dates <- seq(ymd('2009-07-31'),ymd('2022-07-31'), by = '12 months')
Year2_dates <- data.frame(Start_dates, End_dates)

Year2_dates <- Year2_dates %>% 
  mutate(Year2 = format(as.Date(Start_dates, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y"),
          Year2 = as.numeric(Year2) + 1) 
        
Vegetation <- Vegetation %>% 
  left_join(Year2_dates)
         
         
Range_finder <- function(x,y){
  
as.numeric(difftime(x, y, unit = "days"))
}

Range_start <- Vegetation %>% 
  group_by(Year2, ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1) %>% 
  filter(Year != Year2) #had to get rid of first year samples as they were the top row but didn't have a change in year


Range_start <- Range_start %>% 
  mutate(Number_days_start = Range_finder(Date, Start_dates),
         Border_range = Number_days_start * Daily_veg) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(ID, Year2, Date, Border_range) 


Range_end <- Vegetation %>% 
  group_by(Year2, ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==n(),
         Year2 != 2022)

Range_end <- Range_end %>% 
  mutate(Number_days_end = Range_finder(End_dates, Date),
         Border_range = Number_days_end * Daily_veg) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(ID, Year2, Date, Border_range) 

Ranges <- full_join(Range_start, Range_end)

Vegetation <- Vegetation %>% 
  left_join(Ranges)
```